# Javascript audio playing at specific times of day, and randomly choosing from a number of different audios

Tags: javascript, html, audio, random, time

I am working on a website for a friend, just about to apply audio, and have setup this test page to figure it out first.

So the idea is that at specific times of day (9 - 9.05pm, 8.55 - 9am, etc), if you refresh the page, a short audio piece will play once.. this audio piece will be randomly selected from a selection of 2 or 3, with a 'blank' track in there, so sometimes it will be silent. If you refresh again within the time slot another audio will play.

Here is the code..

```
AUDIO TEST !<br />
<br />
Chapel Bedroom @ 8.55 - 9pm<br />
Amazing Song, woodblocks + blank<br />
<br />
Jenny&#39;s Room @ 9 - 9.05pm<br />
Snow, Still a writer + blank<br />
<br />
Kitchen @ 8.55 - 9am<br />
Goosebumps, Rain, Reservation Piece + blank<br />
<br />
Living Room @ 2.05 - 2.10pm<br />
Flute and hidden voice, peacocks, whiterose + blank
<audio id="amazingsong" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/Amazing Song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/Amazing Song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="woodblocks" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/woodblocks.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/woodblocks.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="snow" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/Snow 2016.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/Snow 2016.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="stillawriter" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/Still A Writer [recording Of Maya Deren].mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/Still A Writer [recording Of Maya Deren].ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="goosebumps" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/goosebumps.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/goosebumps.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="rain" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/rain.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/rain.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="reservation" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/reservation piece.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/reservation piece.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="flute" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/flute and hidden voice.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/flute and hidden voice.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="peacocks" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/peacocks.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/peacocks.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>

<audio id="whiterose" preload="auto"><source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/whiterose.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> <source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/whiterose.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /></audio>
<script>

//CHAPEL BEDROOM

mySounds = [ 'amazingsong', 'woodblocks', 'blank1' ]

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) % mySounds.length;
  var id = mySounds[index];
  var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if (hours == 20 && 55 <= minutes && minutes <= 59) {
     audioElement.play();
  }

</script> <script>

//JENNYS ROOM

mySounds = [ 'snow', 'stillawriter', 'blank1' ]

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) % mySounds.length;
  var id = mySounds[index];
  var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if (hours == 21 && 0 <= minutes && minutes <= 5) {
     audioElement.play();
  }

</script> <script>

//KITCHEN

mySounds = [ 'goosebumps', 'rain', 'reservation', 'blank1' ]

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) % mySounds.length;
  var id = mySounds[index];
  var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if (hours == 8 && 55 <= minutes && minutes <= 59) {
     audioElement.play();
  }

</script> <script>

//LIVING ROOM

mySounds = [ 'flute', 'peacocks', 'whiterose', 'blank1' ]

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) % mySounds.length;
  var id = mySounds[index];
  var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if (hours == 14 && 5 <= minutes && minutes <= 10) {
     audioElement.play();
  }

</script>
```

And a link to the test page..

http://sarahboulton.co.uk/tests/audio3.html

So it is working on my side, but my friend said it is not playing for her on her side. Where am I going wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It's 14:27 here, am I supposed to wait till 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me (tested on a mac with safari and chromium):

```
//function to insert autoplay audio
function playFile(fileName){
// append this to the div with id of audio...
$("#audio").append(`<audio autoplay><source src="${fileName}" type='audio/mpeg' /> </audio>`) 
}


//example using jquery onclick
// handle click and add class
$("button").on("click", function(){
  playFile('LINK TO AUDIO FILE GOES HERE')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o90ghm5s/

It uses jQuery to insert the audio tags into an invisible div with autoplay turned on. AFAIK, all browsers still respect autoplay. 
(omitted the time stuff because it was unrelated to the issue, though it should work if you just call the function at the right times)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will not let you play audio without any user interaction (a click or touch). I am not sure if that is the issue here, but you should definitely take care of it.